# Swt.browser inside of Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, swt

How can I put a swt.browser inside of a Jpanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [SWTSwing](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t78918.html), although it's not clear if it supports the Browser component.

If you're looking for a native browser in Java, the jdic project can render Internet Explorer into a swing component. See https://jdic.dev.java.net/documentation/incubator/JDICplus/index.html

Possibly more complete and current is the embedded browser support in NetBeans.
http://wiki.netbeans.org/EmbeddedBrowserPlan68